# how do i prevent adding duplicates items in listview in delphi

Tags: delphi

i have some list inside a list view i want to prevent Adding items that already exist and allow only items that's not exist i search about that before i post my question i find some codes that removes the duplicated items but thats not my point , a little example of what aim trying to achieve , example

```
listview1.Items.Add.caption := 'item1'
listview1.Items.Add.subitems.add:= 'content'

listview1.Items.Add.caption := 'item2'
listview1.Items.Add.subitems.add:= 'content2'

listview1.Items.Add.caption := 'item3'
listview1.Items.Add.subitems.add:= 'content3'

//duplicated line
listview1.Items.Add.caption := 'item1'// here what i want to ignore if exist and add any other items comes below
listview1.Items.Add.subitems.add:= 'content'


listview1.Items.Add.caption := 'item4'
listview1.Items.Add.subitems.add:= 'content4'
```

**any idea on how to achieve that ignore exist items and add what ever other items ?**

Current code

```
if Command = 'CallThis' then
  begin
    if Assigned(MS) then
    begin
      SL := TStringList.Create;
      try
        SL.LoadFromStream(MS);
        for I := 0 to SL.Count -1  do
        begin
            Line := SL.Strings[I];
            ExplodeLine(Line, item, content, num);
            with vieform.list.Items.Add do
            begin
              Caption := StripHTML(item);
              Subitems.Add(content);
              Subitems.Add(num)
            end;
        end;
      finally
        SL.Free;
      end;
      MS.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: i don't know how to implement this procedure

Comment: Just delete the code that adds the duplicates. Or is the real code completely different?

Comment: the code in the question is just example of what iam trying to achieve but in my project i add items to list view from Tstringlist and i call this Tsringlist with command to be added to Listview but each time i call the command list view added the Tstringlist items again and again and again .

Comment: @DelphiStudent Then perhaps you meant to ask an entirely different question. That makes me confident you have a deeper problem with reading your `TStringList`.

Comment: Tstringlist its only holds some items and its not  updated by calling the command and also  it doesn't have repeated items i just use it to show some records also i update the question with my current code  that i use in my project

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what `ExplodeLine` does.

Comment: But, you need to ask a new question "Why am I getting duplicate items in this code?"

Comment: still my question about duplicated items not about TSTRINGLIST Explodeline its function that make space between each string inside Tstringlist , its some code management nothing else .

Comment: @DelphiStudent Exactly my point. This question is about "How to prevent adding duplicate items to a TListView" but you meant to ask "Why am I getting duplicate items from my TStringList?"

Comment: i just explain how i add items :) there is nothing to do with Tstring list with the question , actually Tstringlist its not the  problem at all .

Comment: @DelphiStudent Again, that's exactly my point :) But how do we know it's not the problem? My point is, you need to ask yourself, "Why do I need to add this check in the first place?"

Comment: I still think your `ExplodeLine` procedure might be the culprit, I wouldn't be mentioning it unless I see no cause of your problem in your code. Start with the problem first "I'm getting duplicated items from my list". Then, dig your way to the cause of the problem. It seems your TListView is only the first level of checking you need to do, then work your way backwards. Have you tried using breakpoints and observing the values of these lines?

Comment: i simply showmessage(The result before adding the items ) and there is no duplicated string inside Tstring list thats how i am sure thats not from tstringlist , btw i will delete the exist in list view before adding thats seems the only solution .

Comment: @DelphiStudent But we still can't see all that code that you're just now talking about. That's why you need to ask a new question. Just slapping on a check to prevent adding duplicates to your list view isn't going to solve your problem, but only disguise it :-)

Comment: @DelphiStudent "btw i will delete the exist in list view before adding thats seems the only solution ." You mean you weren't clearing the list in the first place? Was that your problem? Of course you need to clear items out of the list before re-adding them again...

Comment: no thats not my problem btw Thanks.

Comment: Well this question, in its current state, I have answered it for you below already. If you have a different issue, you need to ask a different question. I tried to help you find the root cause of your problem but you need to help me help you :-) So I'll be more than happy to contribute to your other question, but I'm finished with this one.

Comment: Thanks for commenting and answering , your answer is useful and i hope it will help others with some kind of duplicated issues , about asking new question about this  , well never happened because its already asked in this one dragging Tstringlist into the topic is by your investigation on how things works with my project nothing else.

Comment: It's good that you added more realistic code. That helped us understand the real problem. I'd go a lot further than the answer you accepted. Always keep UI separate from underlying data. Regard UI as a view of the data. Hold the data in a non-visual container and then present one or more views of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use the visual controls to store and manage your data. Have a list for all the data and present the data in the listview or any other control you like.

```
// class to store data (shortend)
TMyData = class
  constructor Create( const Item, Content : string );
  property Item : string;
  property Content : string;
end;

// list to organize the data
MyList := TObjectList<TMyData>.Create(
  // comparer, tell the list, when are items equal 
  TComparer<TMyData>.Construct(
    function ( const L, R : TMyData ) : integer
    begin
      Result := CompareStr( L.Item, R.Item );
    end ) );

// create an item
MyData := TMyData.Create( 'item1', 'content1' );

// check for duplicate in list
if not MyList.Contains( MyData ) then
  MyList.Add( MyData )
else
  MyData.Free;

// present the list in a ListView
ListView1.Clear;
for MyData in MyList do
begin
  ListItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  ListItem.Data := MyData; // store a reference to the data item
  ListItem.Caption := MyData.Item;
  ListItem.SubItems.Add( MyData.Content );
end;
```

Thats all

Comment: Take this one step further and use virtual control

Answer (score 2):

Just write your own procedure which does all the work for you. Also helps with your sub items, except I'm not sure what you were trying to do in your code (This is what I'm assuming you were attempting to do)...

```
procedure TForm1.Add(const Caption, Sub: String);
var
  I: TListItem;
  X: Integer;
begin
  for X := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1 do
    if SameText(ListView1.Items[X].Caption, Caption) then Exit;
  I:= ListView1.Items.Add;
  I.Caption:= Caption;
  I.SubItems.Add(Sub);
end;
```

Then, you simply call it like this:

```
Add('Item1', 'Content');
Add('Item2', 'Content2');
Add('Item3', 'Content3');
Add('Item1', 'Content1');
```

That would result in 3 items in the list, because the 4th already exists.

Please note however that this may not actually solve your real underlying issue. If you feel the need to perform this check, then it's probably a good time to re-think your design. The approach you're using makes me believe you're using the `TListView` to store data. UI controls should never be the container of actual data, it should only provide the interface to the user.

Comment: Not sure why someone decided to retract their upvote after adding my edit at the end.